# Desugaring rules for arithmetic operations on 'Num'

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, constants

Constants are polymorphic in Haskell. So when I write:

```
foo = 5
```

This desugars into:

```
foo = fromInteger 5
```

But what if add arithmetic expressions?

```
foo = 42 - 15
```

In what exactly this will be desugared?

```
foo = fromInteger (42 - 15)
```

or

```
for = fromInteger 42 - fromInteger 15
```

Also, what is the easiest and reliable way to observe this?

Answer (score 5):

Haskell has polymorphic literals. (just numbers by default, but GHC has language extensions for polymorphic string literals and polymorphic list literals)

The coercing expressions (like `fromInteger`) only operate on the literal itself, and not the expression, so

```
foo = 42 - 15
```

and

```
foo = fromInteger 42 - fromInteger 15
```

are equivalent.

We can show this is the case by defining a `Num` instance where the behaviour differs (for example, where `+` and `-` are swapped)

```
newtype Inverted a = Inverted {unInvert :: a}
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance (Num a) => Num (Inverted a) where
  (Inverted x) + (Inverted y) = Inverted (x-y)
  (Inverted x) - (Inverted y) = Inverted (x+y)
  signum = Inverted . signum . unInvert
  (Inverted x) * (Inverted y) = Inverted (x*y)
  abs = Inverted . abs . unInvert
  fromInteger = Inverted . fromInteger

base :: Inverted Double
base = 42 - 15

fromBeforeOp :: Inverted Double
fromBeforeOp = fromInteger 42 - fromInteger 15

fromAfterOp :: Inverted Double
fromAfterOp = fromInteger (42 - 15)
```

Both `base` and `fromBeforeOp` give the same (correct with respect to the definition of `Inverted`) answer of `57`, whilst `fromAfterOp` gives `27`.

Answer (score 3):

It is desugared to

```
foo = fromInteger 42 - fromInteger 15
```

You can observe that by trying

```
f :: Double -> Int -> String
f _ _ = "hello"

foo = 42 `f` 15
```

where we used a custom `f` instead of `-`. Here the two literals must be converted to the numeric types before calling `f`. Converting the result of `f` would be meaningless, since it is not a numeric type.

Using `-` does not change the general rule.